# Corrupted IndexBlock 31322 Found in Cache. Related to /.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

How do I go about resolving this error message? It does not cause a crash yet produces:

> Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 31322 found in cache '/Users/macuser123/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'."

I am building a simple layout, java has not been touched yet, only layout elements in XML have been added. Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBasicWhite"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <!--TOP SECTION-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar"
            android:baselineAligned="false">
            <!--Profile Page-->
            <!--Left Side-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numberOfFollowing"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/numberOfFollowing"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/following"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Profile Photo -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:gravity="center">
                <!--Displays Profile Photo-->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/profilealttext"
                    android:src="@drawable/profilepicture" />

                <!--WHITE CROP Over Profile Photo-->
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewCrop"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/profilealttext"
                    android:src="@drawable/profilethumbcrop" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- Right Side -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numberOfFollowers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/numberOfFollowers"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/followers"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--END OF TOP PORTION, PROFILE PICTURE, FOLLOWER/ING INFO-->

        <!--PROFILE Name and Bio Section-->
        <!--SECTION START-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profiledetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileheader"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!--NAME-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/username"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
            <!--BIO-->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/userbio"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/useraddress"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!--SECTION ENDS-->

        <!--PROFILE NAVIGATION BUTTONS-->

        <!--GRAY DIVIDER-->
        <!--This is the gray line!-->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profiledetails"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <!--PROFILE NAVIGATION BUTTONS-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navbuttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/profilepostsbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:scaleX="1.5"
                android:scaleY="1.5"
                android:src="@drawable/groupicon" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/profilepostsbutton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:scaleX="1.5"
                android:scaleY="1.5"
                android:src="@drawable/hunt" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/profilepostsbutton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:scaleX="1.5"
                android:scaleY="1.5"
                android:src="@drawable/quoteicon" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--This is the gray line!-->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/navbuttons"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/divider2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.widget.RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: I would advice you to add some code or more content of what you are doing into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Further to my question -  this isn't code related from my research. I reinstalled Android Studio and started a completely new project. Tried launching it and I am still getting this error with no altered code whatsoever.